# Apex object returning null

Tags: apex, object, null

I have this Apex class where I have custom objects as defined and debug statements. From the code it seems it is not able to build subObject here.

```
global class TestApexClass {
   global static void buildObject(string fname, string lname) {
      Ethnicity e = new Ethnicity('North America', 'Mixed');
      System.debug('location: ' + e.location);
      MyPersonObject obj = new MyPersonObject(fname, lname, e);
      System.debug('personObject: ' + obj);
   }
   public class MyPersonObject {
      public String firstName;
      public String lastName;
      public Ethnicity e;
      public MyPersonObject(String fname, String lname, Ethnicity e) {
         firstName = fname; lastName = lname; e = e;
      }
   }
   public class Ethnicity {
      public String location;
      public String race;
      public Ethnicity(String l, String r) {
         location = l; race = r;
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my debug output:
location: North America
personObject: MyPersonObject:[e=null, firstName=John, lastName=Doe]

Is there a reason why "e" returns a null value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of "[name shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm)." You named both the parameter `e` and the property `e`, so you're just assigning the value to itself (i.e. nothing happens). You need to use `this` if you shadow a variable and need access to the class variable instead:

```
     firstName = fname; lastName = lname; this.e = e;
```

I always recommend avoiding using the same name between class properties and function parameter names,  because this tends to cause unintentional bugs.

```
  public MyPersonObject(String fname, String lname, Ethnicity eth) {
     firstName = fname; lastName = lname; e = eth;
  }
```

The alternative is to always use `this` to refer to class variables, but that's almost always inefficient in terms of time it takes to write code and CPU execution time.

As a final note, avoid using one-letter variable names. These are non-descriptive, and tends to lead to code being more difficult to understand in exchange for saving a few characters; longer variable names are self-documenting. The exception to this rule are names like `i` or `x` for loop indices.